# Node.js -- Why is not able to read the file form the correct path

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to read a file, but I got the following **error:**

> > false { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './www/text.html']   errno: -2,   code: 'ENOENT',   syscall: 'open',
> >     path: './www/text.html' }

I verify the text.html exist in a www file

here is my code

```
 var http = require('http');
 var fs = require('fs');

 http.createServer((req,res)=>{

 var fsFile = './www' + req.url;

 fs.readFile(fsFile ,(err,data)=>{

   console.log(req.url) 

   if(err){

      console.log('false',err);

   }else{

      res.write(data)

   }

  res.end();

 })

}).listen(7077)
```

What can I do to solve this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: could you give your project structure, I wanna know the relativity of your file and the server accessing it in relativity

Comment: @sduduzo gumede The test.html and a www  file are in the root directory . The test.html is in the www file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File paths for `.readFile()` need to be absolute.

Try this:  (note the use of the global variable `__dirname` on line 4)

```
var http = require('http'); var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    var fsFile = __dirname + '/www' + req.url;
    fs.readFile(fsFile ,(err,data)=>{
        console.log(req.url)
        if(err){
            console.log('false',err);
        }else{
            res.write(data)
        }
        res.end();
    })
}).listen(7077)
```

`__dirname` returns the absolute file path that the node process was called in.

A synonym for this variable is the function `process.cwd()` (current working directory)